# How does the shape of radioactive material effect its critical mass?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, nuclear-engineering

If critical mass is defined by the amount of fissile material required to sustain nuclear fission. Assuming a subcritical mass object, and knowing radioactive materials can merely by chance break apart due to radioactive decay releasing neutrons in random directions causing only minor reactions because the object isn't at critical mass (not enough material in the right quantity, shape, pressure etc or without enough help from a neutron reflector) the majority of the neutrons will fly out of the object with no sustained reaction. Simply put the object is merely radioactive.

Given that (specifically calling to the importance of shape in critical mass), shouldn't there be a possibility, albeit very small, of a mass object that would be critical given it had a spherical shape but instead has a cylindrical shape(meaning its not at critical mass because of its current shape), of having a sustained reaction. I could understand if criticality was defined solely by temperature, enrichment or some other factors but shouldn't the size shape and density(especially since an object can't maintain a perfectly even density) cause a fairly large ambiguity in calculating the critical mass of an object.

My questions are: 
Firstly, are there any flaws in my current thinking/understanding?

If not how can you calculate critical mass accurately given such a large dependence on chance?

Why hasn't at least one stored nuclear weapons undergone a reaction(not necessarily an explosion but a sustained reaction)? -I know that the fissile material used in atomic weapons are kept in pieces or at a lower density so they aren't at critical mass, but shouldn't this have happened by chance to at least 1 part of the core to at least one weapon?

And how do you actually calculate the critical mass of an object?

If you could provide a lecture or some resource that shows how critical mass is calculated, it would greatly help my understanding.

Comment: Critical mass is lowest for spheres.

Comment: this might have an answer  for you, but you have to go through it as it is a photo https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5040422

Comment: Book recommendation: “The Los Alamos Primer,” a set of notes used by new scientists to the Manhattan Project, is declassified. This is a question which makes people who know the answer try to remember the terms of their security clearance.

Answer (score 1):

Figures quoted for "Critical mass" assume that the neutron sources (the atoms of radioactive material), are as close as possible to each other, namely a sphere.  If an object has barely enough mass for critical mass, but is not as close as possible (not a sphere), then the chain reaction would not occur.

Btw, the speed of the reaction is only what you would call an explosion if the critical mass is much more than critical mass, and it occurs very suddenly.  A bomb uses some high velocity explosive i.e. c-4, forcing the mass together in order to reach critical mass very quickly.  Otherwise, it is informally called a "fissle".  Critical mass occurs slowly, causing a melting, radioactive mess has a chain reaction for a while, and continues for a while until there is no longer critical mass.  This is like a nuclear reactor, but more messy and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the nuclear material is important, as it may increase the probability of neutrons encountering nuclei and causing secondary fission events. The *shape* is however understood in a rather general sense: not as a geometrical shape by itself, but also how it is affected by likely environment, containers, etc. [The known accidents involving accidental creation of a critical mass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticality_accident) invariably involve reflectors.

Nuclear weapons are, of course, designed in such a way as to reduce the risk of accidental detonation. The designs have so far shown themselves foolproof, as manifested in some [extreme cases where the nuclear weapons were lost, e.g., in an airplane crash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_nuclear_accidents).

Answer (score 0):

Critical mass, for a given material, is determined by leakage of neutrons, and reflection of neutrons from outside materials.  Leakage depends on the shape, and reflection depends on the type and geometry of outside materials.  Leakage is minimized when the surface to volume ratio is minimum.

With less than optimum shape, a critical configuration can be achieved but with greater mass than for the optimum shape.